# gRPC: Turn a message proto into a List<message> (C# .Net6)

Tags: c#, grpc, ienumerable

I want to turn a messageResponse from a protocol buffer into a
`IEnumerable<messageResponse>`
so in the service will return me an `IEnumerable<messageResponse>`

Proto I have:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "ProjectName.Protos";

package Banana;

service Banana {
   rpc GetAllBananas (MessageRequest) returns (ListBananasResponse);
}

//How to Turn this to IEnumerable<> ?
message ListBananasResponse{
    string bananaName = 1;
    string bananaInfo = 2;
}

message MessageRequest{
    string message = 1;
}
```

And this is my the BananaService.cs

```
using Grpc.Core;
using ProjectName.Protos;

namespace ProjectName.Services
{

    public class BananaService : Banana.BananaBase
    {
      //The Method should return a IEnumerable list of bananas 
         //want to do Task<IEnumerable<ListBananasResponse>>
      public override Task<ListBananasResponse> GetAllBananas(MessageRequest request, 
      ServerCallContext context)
        {
            var lstbananas = new IEnumerable<ListBananasResponse>();
            return lstbananas;
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to do this and if so, how to do it? (I'm Using C# .Net6)

Any answer is welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way of specifying that a protobuf RPC returns a list of responses in one go. There are two options here:

- Add a message that has a repeated field, and return *that* from the RPC
- Use a streaming RPC

Unless you *actually* need streaming, I'd strongly advise the former approach. So your .proto file would include a section like this:

```
service Banana {
   rpc GetAllBananas (MessageRequest) returns (ListBananasResponse);
}

message Banana {
    string name = 1;
    string info = 2;
}

message ListBananasResponse {
    repeated Banana bananas = 1;
}
```

You'd then implement the RPC with something like:

```cs
public override Task<ListBananasResponse> GetAllBananas(MessageRequest request, 
    ServerCallContext context)
{
    var banana1 = new Banana { Name = "name1", Info = "info1" };
    var banana2 = new Banana { Name = "name2", Info = "info2" };
    var response = new ListBananasResponse
    {
        Bananas = { banana1, banana2 }
    };
    return Task.FromResult(response);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will test that form and see if that works or not

Comment: I need to add some import from the using 'repeated' ??

Comment: @JoséLeal: No, `repeated` is a keyword in proto. See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3

Comment: That helps and resolves the simple problem so I will give a 'yes' to my simple problem but I have other problem is how to do with DB, because I need to call all bananas, not just 2 like that example, but the list problem is correct

Comment: @JoséLeal: You can add an `IEnumerable<Banana>` to `response.Bananas` in the same way - this was just *one* example. (You didn't provide much context, making it pretty hard to give a helpful answer...)